# Powershell query features returns wrong result

Tags: powershell, feature-upgrade

I'm currently writing a powershell script which upgrades a set of solutions then a set of features from those solutions.

After the solution upgrades everything looks great until I Call QueryFeatures which proceeds to return an empty result set.

```
 # This is just sample code
 $site.QueryFeatures((Get-SPFeature | Where { $_.DisplayName -match "$FeatureName" } | Select -First 1).Id, $true)
```

I've tried disposing the site before use then creating a new site with new-object, and even [Clearing the Object Model Cache](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/5ea46e07-a4b0-4bab-b698-9b6eeb695607). The only thing that works is to open a new powershell window and issuing the same command.

However this is part of a long running script so this obviously isn't the best solution. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common issue when writing deployment scripts for SharePoint in PowerShell that often you need to spawn a new PowerShell in order to:

- Get rid of cahcing
- Get a clean AppDomain without old version of dlls loaded

The version of the dlls is going to be your next problem as I assume you're going to call Upgrade on the returned features, which might want to call into a FeatureReceiver which needs to be the new version.

So it's common to write the main script as a series of:

> powershell -noexit -command &'Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;substep.ps1' -sta

Comment: Yeah this is the solution I ended up with

Comment: The issue was the farm and feature definitions were already loaded and there is no way to refresh them.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a timing issue. Stick a 60 second wait in your script just before this point and see if that helps

Comment: No it's not a timing issue

Comment: You should also poll, not just wait 60s, as a async action could take more or less than 60s especially over a large farm.