# How to upgrade one specific feature only with powershell

Tags: powershell, feature-upgrade

I created a farm feature and then I upgraded it.

According to the documentation, the upgrade-spfeature -scope farm will upgrade all features requiring upgrade.
[Feature upgrade (part 5) – using PowerShell to upgrade Features (this article)](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/08/feature-upgrade-part-5-using-powershell.html)

I only want to ugprade one and it has to be with PowerShell.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

im presuming that the feature is in a wsp so you should be able to do this:

```
Update-SPSolution –Identity YourSolutionName.wsp –LiteralPath “C:\YourSolutionName.wsp” –GacDeployment
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607724.aspx

**EDIT**

forgot to mention you need to change the version number ;) for a more finer detail you can follow this:

> 1.Open the Feature Designer for Feature2. In the Properties pane, set the version number to 1.0.0.0. Where no version number is specified, a
>   default of 0.0.0.0 is assumed. Version numbers must contain four
>   components.
>
> 2.From the Build menu, select Deploy. This will deploy our version 1 solution to the farm.
>
> 3.In the Feature Designer, click the Manifest button at the bottom of the page. Expand the Edit Options section to display the Manifest
>   Template. Replace the template XML with the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <UpgradeActions>
  <VersionRange>
  <CustomUpgradeAction Name="MyUpgrade"/>
  </VersionRange>
  </UpgradeActions>
  </Feature>
```

> By attaching this XML to the feature definition, we’re defining the
>   steps that should be taken to upgrade existing features. The
>   CustomUpgradeAction element specifies that we’re using a feature
>   receiver to perform the upgrade programmatically. In this example, we
>   haven’t specified a version range, so this upgrade action will apply
>   for all versions. If we needed to include different upgrade actions
>   for different versions we could add this:

```
  <Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <UpgradeActions>
      <VersionRange BeginVersion="1.0.0.0" EndVersion="2.0.0.0">
        <CustomUpgradeAction Name="V2Upgrade"/>
      </VersionRange>
      <VersionRange BeginVersion="2.0.0.0" EndVersion="3.0.0.0">
        <CustomUpgradeAction Name="V3Upgrade"/>
      </VersionRange>
    </UpgradeActions>
  </Feature>
```

> 4.In the Properties pane, change the Version number for Feature 2 to 2.0.0.0.
>
> Note
>
> Within the Properties pane are options to set the Upgrade Actions
>   Receiver Assembly and Class properties. These properties allow a
>   feature to use a separate assembly for handling standard feature
>   events such as Activate and Deactivate and a separate assembly for
>   handling upgrade events. This facility is useful for retrofitting
>   upgrade capabilities to a feature if the existing receiver assembly
>   isn’t available or can’t be altered for some reason.
>
> 5.For the sake of simplicity, we’ll implement our upgrade code in our existing feature receiver. In the Feature2.EventReceiver.cs file, add
>   the following code:
>
> Code View: Scroll / Show All

```
public override void FeatureUpgrading(
                             SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties,
                             string upgradeActionName,
                             IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
      switch (upgradeActionName)
      {
        case "MyUpgrade":
          if (properties.Feature.Parent is SPWeb)
          {
            SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
            using (Stream s = properties.Definition.GetFile(
                                              "FirstElement\\MyConfig.xml"))
            {
              using (XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(s))
              {
                rdr.ReadToDescendant("List");
                do
                {
                  string listName = rdr.GetAttribute("name").ToString();
                  SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);

                  if (myList != null)
                  {
                   myList.Description += "- Updated";

                    myList.Update();
                  }
                } while (rdr.ReadToNextSibling("List"));
              }
            }
          }
           break;
         default:
           break;
       }
    }
 }
```

> Notice the use of a switch block in this code snippet to handle the
>   upgradeActionName. This value is specified in the Name attribute of
>   the CustomUpgradeAction element in the feature manifest.
>
> 6.If we deploy our updated feature using Visual Studio, our existing version will be removed first, which will make it impossible to test
>   our upgrade process. Instead, we’ll package our solution using Visual
>   Studio and deploy it manually. From the Build menu, select Package.
>
> 7.To test our upgrade process quickly, we can use PowerShell to upgrade a single feature. Choose Start | SharePoint 2010 Management
>   Shell, and then enter the following script:

```
  update-spsolution -identity Example 19.wsp -literalpath c:\code\example19\→
  example19\bin\debug\example19.wsp -gacdeployment
```

> Note This command should be entered as a single line.
>
> 8.This command will upgrade the Example19 solution package to the latest version. We can confirm this by entering the following script:

```
$featureName="Example19_feature2"
$latestVersion=(get-spfeature|where {$_.DisplayName -eq $featureName}).Version
$web=get-spweb http://<your Server Name>/example19
$theFeature=$web.Features|Where {$_.Definition.DisplayName -eq $featureName}
$currentVersion=theFeature.Version
write-host "Current Version: $currentVersion, Latest Version: $latestVersion"
```

> If all is well, the resultant output should be this:
>
> Current Version: 1.0.0.0, Latest Version: 2.0.0.0
>
> 9.We can upgrade a single feature using the following script:

```
$web=get-spweb http://<your Server Name>/example19
$theFeature=$web.Features|Where {$_.Definition.DisplayName -eq $featureName}
$theFeature.Upgrade($false)
```

> 10.Any errors that occur as part of the upgrade process will be shown in the PowerShell window. However, we can confirm that our upgrade was
>   successful by issuing the following command:

```
  write-host ($theFeature).Version
```

> The new version number should be reported as 2.0.0.0.

http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/sharepoint-2010---packaging-and-deployment-model---features-(part-3)---upgrading-features.aspx

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with the feature upgrade toolkit that I am talking about from Chris O Brien.  The solution has been already installed, but there is a feature that changed from V1 to V2 and I want to upgrade it using powershell(from the toolkit developed by Chris), see link, I wonder if that is possible or not, because his example only shows the command that will upgrade ALL farm features at once.

Comment: I think this last part is all I need: $web=get-spweb http://<your Server Name>/example19
$theFeature=$web.Features|Where {$_.Definition.DisplayName -eq $featureName}
$theFeature.Upgrade($false)

Comment: At point 9 I get `<nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>`

Answer (score 3):

You can call Upgrade method on desired SPFeature object.
Depending on the feature scope you might need different code to fetch that SPFeature object.

Example for site scoped feature:

```
$id = new-object System.Guid("<feature_id_here>")
$site = Get-SPSite "<site_url_here>"
$feature = $site.Features[$id]
$feature.Upgrade($false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Ali Jafer gave a very comprehensive answer but in my case these commands using Feature Name did not work. I used Feature ID and here is how my powershell commands look like.

```
Update-SPSolution –Identity "Example.wsp" –LiteralPath "E:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Example.wsp" –GacDeployment  


$featureId = new-object System.Guid("FeatureID here")  
$latestVersion=(get-spfeature|where {$_.Id -eq $featureId}).Version 
$web=get-spweb "URL"  
$theFeature=$web.Features|Where {$_.Definition.Id -eq $featureId} 
$currentVersion=$theFeature.Version 
write-host "Current Version: $currentVersion, Latest Version: $latestVersion" 



$web=get-spweb "URL"  
$theFeature=$web.Features|Where {$_.Definition.Id -eq $featureId} 
$theFeature.Upgrade($false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell to execute `SPFeature.Upgrade()` after running the `Update-SPSolution` cmdlet, it is necessary to close the session and open a new instance of PowerShell (PowerGUI etc) before executing `SPFeature.Upgrade()`. Failure to do so will cause the feature to appear as if no upgrade is available.  I experienced this when upgrading a Web-scope feature (so it may be limited to Web-scope and not an issue for Site-scope) Found others with the same experience [here](http://damneddutch.blogspot.com/2012/08/upgrading-sharepoint-content-types.html) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33702/powershell-query-features-returns-wrong-result)

Comment: I had this problem with Site scoped features. Thanks for the tip