# SharePoint 2019: feature 'MySiteMicroBlog' needs upgrade ; Database is up to date, but some sites are not completely upgraded

Tags: migration, feature-upgrade, mysites, 2019

- Test SharePoint 2019 MinRole farm patched to KB4464556 May/2019
- Tested Mysites database migration by restoring a full backup from a production 2016 farm but for several MySites this feature needs an upgrade:

> Feature 'MySiteMicroBlog' Current Version: 15.0.5.0 < Latest Version: 15.0.6.0. Feature needs and upgrade.

- In Central Administration > Manage Databases Upgrade Status
  MySites Status:

> Database is up to date, but some sites are not completely upgraded.

Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'MySiteMicroBlog' (Id: 15/GUID') in Web 'http://mysites/personal/username'. Exception: 0x80070002

How can I upgrade this feature?

Comment: Patching to KB4464518 (April/2019); rebooting servers; deleting the database from CA>Content Databases and adding it back; and clearing config cache on all servers did not fix the issue.

Comment: Root cause: Feature 'MySiteMicroBlog' needs upgrade on several MySites from Current Version: 15.0.5.0 to Latest Version: 15.0.6.0. How can I do this? Updating my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I used Mount-SPContentDatabase after restoring backup in SQL and it runs an upgrade on the database, results gets logged in the ULS LOGS folder file name starting like: Upgrade-YYYMMDD-HHMMSS-###-xxxx.log.

- Using ULSViewer, I filtered by Level: ERROR and Message: Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'MySiteMicroBlog'
- Got all Mysites URLs failing to upgrade MySiteMicroBlog" feature from that log
- Using [cmdlets shown here on steps 8-10](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76156/how-to-upgrade-one-specific-feature-only-with-powershell) I upgraded  "MySiteMicroBlog" feature on each MySites (Note: Upgrade returns exception 0x80070002 but it works anyway).
- Logged as the farm account in Central Administration, delete MySites content database, wait 2 min aprox and added it back.

Following these steps changed database status to "No Action Required" and I finally resolved this issue

Comment: At point 9 I get `<nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>`